# Navigation Drawer Xamarin Android

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I trying to use Navigation Drawer in Xamarin Android, but i get this issue:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Can someone explain me why i get this error? and how can i fix it?

I already use Support Library v7:

22.2.0.0 - 23.1.1.1 - 23.2.1 - 24.2.1.0 and nothing help me.

Main.axml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Main content view-->
    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Support V7 Action Bar Drawer Toggle"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The Left Navigation Drawer -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#818181"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#E3F2FD" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#E2E2E2"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#9E9E9E" />

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using SupportToolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

namespace LeftDrawable
{
    [Activity(Label = "LeftDrawable", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon",
        Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]

    public class MainActivity : ActionBarActivity
    {
        private SupportToolbar toolbar;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            toolbar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: refer to the [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36875/android-support-v7-error-after-updating)  uninstall the XF, delete bin/obj folder, restart VS, install back the XF, rebuild whole solution

Comment: Try inherit form AppCompatActivity